# C++ basic float parsing code slightly different result from std::atof

Tags: c++, parsing, optimization, floating-point, ieee-754

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

#define LIKELY(expr) (__builtin_expect(!!(expr), 1))
#define UNLIKELY(expr) (__builtin_expect(!!(expr), 0))

bool abscmp(double a, double b)
{
  if (isnan(a) && isnan(b)) return true;
  if (isnan(a) ^ isnan(b)) return false;
  return a == b;
}

template <typename T>
inline __attribute__((always_inline)) T ParseFloat(const char *a) {
  static constexpr T multers[] = {
    0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0.0001, 0.00001, 0.000001, 0.0000001, 0.00000001, 0.000000001, 0.0000000001, 0.00000000001,
    0.000000000001, 0.0000000000001, 0.00000000000001, 0.000000000000001, 0.0000000000000001, 0.00000000000000001
  };
  static_assert(std::is_floating_point_v<T>);
  int i = (a[0] == '-') | (a[0] == '+');
  T res = 0.0;
  int sign = 1 - 2 * (a[0] == '-');
  if (UNLIKELY(!a[0])) return NAN;

  while (a[i] && a[i] != '.') {
    if (UNLIKELY(a[i] < '0' || a[i] > '9')) {
      return NAN;
    }
    res = res * static_cast<T>(10.0) + a[i] - '0';
    i++;
  }

  if (LIKELY(a[i] != '\0')) {
    i++;
    int j = i;
    //T mult = 0.1;
    while (a[i]) {
      if (UNLIKELY(a[i] < '0' || a[i] > '9')) {
        return NAN;
      }
      res = res + (a[i] - '0') * multers[i - j];
      // res = res + (a[i] - '0') * mult;
      // mult *= 0.1;
      i++;
    }
  }

  return res * sign;
}

int main()
{
  string inputs[] = {
    "31.0911863667",
    "30.9500",
    "225.1293333333",
    "16.4850",
    "29.0507297346",
    "147.9440517474",
    "28.8500",
    "213.4600",
    "212.9105553333",
    "199.1553333333",
    "19.5884123000",
    "3092458.37500000000"
  };

  int n = sizeof(inputs) / sizeof(inputs[0]);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    float res1 = std::atof(inputs[i].c_str());
    float res2 = ParseFloat<double>(inputs[i].c_str());
    if (!abscmp(res1, res2)) {
      cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(20) << "CompareConvert " << res1 << " " << res2 << " " << std::string(inputs[i]) << std::endl;
    } else {
      cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(20) << "Correct " << res1 << std::endl;
    }
  }
}
```

I'm writing a simple parser (with full validity check) because `std::atof` is too slow (`ParseFast` is 3.2x faster on average in my test inputs - parsing GBs of CSV file). The formula is very simple, `res = res * 10 + (a[i] - '0');`. But it gives slightly different result.

I'm aware that this is because of limitations of IEEE-754 floating point. But is there any cheap way to make `ParseFast` give exact same result as `std::atof`? I need them to be exactly the same because it's interacting with a legacy module that uses sha256sum to check equality instead of `fabs(a - b) < epsilon`

Command to run: `g++ -o main main.cpp -O3 -std=c++17`, gcc 10.2.0

**Edit:** Explanation why last input is wrong: the decimal part `0.375` is exactly between 2 possible values `0.5` and `0.25`. But with this parsing method, at the digit `.3`, the intermediate result will be `3092458.0 + 0.3 == 3092458.25` because of rounding. Adding `0.075` to that will still give `3092458.25`.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but since you write your function in C++, why not use `std::string` directly as an argument? Also instead of `a[i] < '0' || a[i] > '9'` why not use `!std::isdigit(a[i])`? And if you want to loop using indexes, use an `unsigned` integer type. Oh, and your bitwise operator "tricks" are really nothing more than tricks. If you avoid them and use normal operators and expressions that are easy to understand (and maintain!) the compiler will have better chances of optimizing them well. Such tricks are usually misguided.

Comment: It's plugged into another module, which requires `const char*` as input. For `!std::isdigit(a[i])`, yeah maybe it's a good idea and I'll try that. For `int` vs `unsigned`, I just use `int` whenever possible because I don't see any performance difference

Comment: `std::atof` returns a type of `double`. You are using `float` for your internal calculations. You may want to first compare `ParseFloat<double>` and see how close you are. At first glance, I'd say that `mult` could be problematic. As you probably know, `0.1` is not cleanly representable in binary and so not only is that an immediate possible issue, but will also be compounded when you do `mult *= 0.1`

Comment: @paddy Oh, I saw "f" in `atof` and thought it returns float without checking (also because `std::atod` exist). Using `ParseFloat<double>` gives exact same result in most cases, but it's still wrong on the last input. I also test `ParseFloat<double>` performance, and it's actually very similar with `ParseFloat<float>` in my dataset.

Comment: As an exercise, you might try tackling the problem from the viewpoint of how floats are actually stored. Perform binary long division to generate the mantissa to the required precision, pull off the first bit and calculate the exponent. It might not be performant, but it is more likely to be close to what's happening in standard implementations. Perhaps even take a look at how GNU standard library does it.

Comment: 0.1 has no exact representation as binary floating point; multiplying by it will inevitably introduce errors.  If there were a faster way to get the same results as `atof`, including error checking, don't you think `atof` would already be doing it?

Comment: How fast it is is entirely irrelevant until it produces the same output. You can get the wrong answer in zero time, but that's not the objective. I suggest you're tilting at windmills here. `atof()` has been worked over for 50 years, and there are reasons for its performance: notably all the special cases it has to cater for. One of your biggest problems here is that `0.1` and friends are already inaccurate before you've even executed any code at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've correctly noticed, the problem is that intermediate results are already imprecise, and this adds up. For example, storing `.2` intermediately is already imprecise, even though it may be followed by `5`, which would make it `.25`, and this would be exactly representable.

You need to accumulate the fractional part of the floating point number as an integer (still a float, but with no fractional part), and then divide once at the end to adjust the exponent:

```cpp
  // ...
  if (LIKELY(a[i] != '\0')) {
    T fraction = 0; // fractional part as an integer
    T power = 1;    // turns to 1, 10, 100, 1000, ... each loop iteration
    i++;
    while (a[i]) {
      if (UNLIKELY(a[i] < '0' || a[i] > '9')) {
        return NAN;
      }
      // note: additional logic is required to make sure that trailing
      //       zeros in the fraction cannot decrease the precision
      power *= T{10};
      fraction = fraction * T{10} + (a[i] - '0');
      i++;
    }

    // note: 'power' can also be obtained from a look-up table like in
    //       your original code.
    //       Benchmark to make sure that it's actually faster to use a table.
    res += fraction / power; // perform one division in the end, e.g. 375 / 100
  }
  
  return std::copysign(res, sign); // note: prefer copysign over multiplication
}
```

*See [live example on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/Y6xsa3hx7)*

Even with these changes, it is probably better to use third-party libraries, as @cpplearner has recommended. Standard library functions like `std::strtof` or `std::to_chars` may not provide the best performance, and the performance will vary form standard library to standard library.

While your solution may be faster on some platforms, it might perform much worse on a platform where floating point multiplication and division are more expensive. Floating point numbers are hard.

Comment: Okay. I'll check this solution and compare it with `fast_float` library. Thanks

Comment: This code is incorrect. For binary64, there will be rounding errors in `power` when there are more than 22 digits, and `fraction/power` will have a rounding error that can make the final sum incorrect. (Even though 17 significant digits suffice to distinguish binary64 numbers if chosen suitably, there may be leading zeroes (not significant digits) and/or the user may be giving many digits for a number that is near the rounding transition.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil yeah, implementing this fully correctly is pretty difficult, especially when including denormalized numbers etc. This code at least works in simple cases, so it is an improvement over OP's original. This kind of stuff is really best done by 3rd party libs.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using the fast_float library (https://github.com/fastfloat/fast_float). It is claimed to be 4x to 10x faster than `strtod` (glibc's `atod` is just a simple wrapper of `strtod`).

Comment: I'll checkout this. Thanks!